# What are the ways to protect javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to prevent a web app from being stored and operated from local file system.

The app has proprietary front end work-space, built with JS & many other libraries, which must be available for usage only if the user is logged in over the domain with active internet.

If any user attempt to save the page and relevant files to local file system and try opening the workspace, it must be prevented.

Is there any possibility to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

If someone really wants to look at the code that's being run, there's no way to prevent it, because it's running on *their machine*, and they can do anything they want with their machine, including examining network requests (such as from their browser, or from their OS).

If there is information that the client should not be able to access under any circumstances, the only solution is to not send that information to the client in the first place.

Now, there are methods to check whether a script is being run from a webpage or a file, eg:

```
if (window.location.href.startsWith('file:')) {
  throw new Error();
}
```

But the user may still examine the script and tamper with it if they desire.

Comment: I had a similar dilemma a while ago where the front end of the app was built in html and all the components were js also built onto the static webpage. The end result for building my sites was to incorporate php and improve the dynamic components strictly in php to load on session stored php variables echoing html code. Granted this doesn't stop them from seeing the front end, but the back end builds are more secretive now. Hope this helps.